# MS ACCESS get records that equal to combo box selection

Tags: ms-access, combobox

I have a table which has 3 columns:
Fnumber(ID)
Status - it can be "Free to use" or "In use"

I want to have a combo box from which the user can select a status: "Free to use" or "In use"
to pull out all Fnumbers(ID) which are free or taken.
And populate text boxes with the result.

I have a form which I have bound to the table from which I want to pull out the information.
I tried creating a combo box which would pull the StatusID from another table and then change the text boxes according to the selection, but it doesn't work.

I can do what I want with a query that will run on update of the combo box, but I want to have text boxes and for them to populate only "Free" or "In use" Fnumbers.

I hope someone can help me,
thanks in advance!

Comment: You show only 2 fields from table, not 3. Is fieldname actually "Fnumber(ID)" or just "Fnumber"? Strongly advise not to use spaces nor punctuation/special characters in naming convention. Really should provide table names and sample data as text tables. You want to use UNBOUND combobox to select criteria to filter form? "doesn't work" means what - error message, wrong result, nothing happens? What exactly did you try? Review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-62.html

Comment: If you want to show multiple IDs in textbox then you need VBA codes.